# I am trying to remove last character in column based on the given condition. If the last character is A. I want it to be removed (I am using python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-cleaning

My Data

```
30-Apr-18 A           30-Apr-18
30-Apr-18 A           30-Apr-18
```

I have a column with dates and some of the dates have A next to them. So when I import the data. Its getting recognized as an object. I want it to be just a date without A next to it.

df is the data frame and start is the column with dates I am using df[start] to bring in start column and function if it has A, remove A and return just date.

I want to remove based on the given condition. I have tried to use this below line code.

`df[Start].apply(lambda x = x.strip(x[-1]) if x[-1] == 'A'))`

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what is wrong with your code.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-383-2b6379458169>", line 1
    df[Start].apply(lambda x = x.strip(x[-1]) if (x[-1] == 'A'))
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax I am getting this error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe the input format in more detail. Is it all on one line or in one string like that—or what? It also looks like you're using a pandas dataframe. If so, tag your question properly (add those tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SyntaxError error you are getting is because the `lambda` should be followed by `:`, not `=`:

```
df[Start] = df[Start].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip(' A'))
```

Comment: Great worked. Thanks for suggestion                       
df['Start'] = df['Start'].apply(lambda x:x.rstrip('A'))

Answer (score 0):

`df[start]` should be `df['start']`

Edit: and as the other answer said, it should be `lambda x:` not `lambda x =`